# Multiple values from checkbox to array C# WPF

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, checkbox

I'm trying to pass to Double values into an array so I can use them for quering.

For example. I want to assign the values 7.895540 and 57.949769 as parameters on a checkbox and then pass those values into a double array using databinding when that checkbox is checked

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
   <CheckBox Content="City1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="5,271,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              IsChecked="{Binding coordinatesArray, Parameter=7.895540 57.949769,  DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
```

The code is wrong, but I have noe idea how to assign the values and then passing them to the array.

Comment: Not clear, what do you want to achieve? And what's stopping you? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: The plan is to have multiple checkboxes with pairs of double attached to them. The values are coordinate pairs to be used in limiting results from queries based on geographical location. Say 1, 1 is London and 2, 2 is New York. By checking the box for 1,1 results are limited to London. By checking the box with 2,2 the results are limited to New York and by checking both the resuluts are limited to New York and London. Of course when not checking either you have noe geographical limitations

Comment: The problem is assigning multiple values to one checkbox and then passing those values to an array. I have no idea how..

Comment: I have not tried too much so far as I don't know how to start. I know how to solve it with a single value, but not when i need to send to values at once

Comment: @user3391541: I have a hunch I would have a better idea of what you are asking if you showed how you would solve it with a single value. What is the `Parameter` property of your binding supposed to do; where does that value go to?

Comment: @user3391541 i didnt understood fully what you are trying to do,but if you wanted to send two double value to an array when someone "Check" the checkbox, why dont you write your logic inside a "Checked EventHandler"?

Comment: If I only had one value this works:  IsChecked="{Binding cursorLimit, ConverterParameter=50, Converter={StaticResource ParamToIntConverter}}"  

The parameter proptery is supposed to send it's values to an array as such  public double[] coordinatesArray { get; set; }. Then later I plan to use those values in a query. But that's a different topic.

@user1767798 can you provide an example of the soloution you're proposing? It should be said that I want to solve this using databinding and not code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "Command" property in the checkbox to Bind to your command and send "IsChecked" value as a command parameter. Commands http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx
Inside your Command you can use whatever logic you wanted to implement. You have to implement ICommand in your solution.

```
mainwindow.xaml
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox"  Name="checkBox1" Command="{Binding YourCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay} />

viewmodel.cs

void YourCommand(object parameter)
{
    // do your logic

}
```

Comment: I've already implmented ICommand for some other functions so this looks like a good soloution! Thanks.